# Chain Rule Second Order PDE

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, chain-rule

Consider second order PDE: $x\phi_{xx}+2x^2\phi_{xy}-\phi_x=x^3$

My characteristic variables are:
$\xi=y-x^2$ and $\eta=y$

$\phi_x = \Phi_\xi.\xi_x+\Phi_\eta.\eta_x=-2x\Phi_\xi$

$\phi_{xx} = -2\Phi_\xi+4x^2\Phi_{\xi\xi}$

$\phi_y = \Phi_\xi+\Phi_\eta$

$\phi_{xy}$ = $-2x(\Phi_{\xi\xi}+\Phi_{\xi\eta})$

I am having trouble understanding how in $\phi_{xx}$, where the second term came from and how they deduced the chain rule for $\phi_{xy}$.

Comment: What are $\phi$ and $\Phi$?

Comment: general solution form. $\phi(x,y)$

Comment: What is $\Phi$?

Comment: In terms of $\xi , \eta$, the unknown function $\phi(x,y)$ becomes $\Phi(\xi, \eta)$    that is, $\phi(x,y)$ = $\Phi(\xi(x,y), \eta(x,y))$